# How to render charts in Databricks using Plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly, databricks

I am trying to render charts using Plotly library in Databricks. However, no image is rendered. I use for example this statement:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly import graph_objs as go

    # Initialize plotly
    init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

    daily_df=df

    def plotly_df(df, title=''):
        """Visualize all the dataframe columns as line plots."""
        common_kw = dict(x=df.index, mode='lines')
        data = [go.Scatter(y=df[c], name=c, **common_kw) for c in df.columns]
        layout = dict(title=title)
        fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
        iplot(fig, show_link=False)

    plotly_df(daily_df)
```

There is no output. Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: Plotly has updated its library to support better rendering in Databricks.  See the answer above.

From looking at [the docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/plotly.html#plotly-in-python-notebooks), you have to specify `output_type='div'` and pass the plot object to `displayHTML()`.  Here's a working example in a Python notebook or cell:

```py
## Install & import plotly
!pip install plotly
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(2000)
y = np.random.randn(2000)

# Instead of simply calling plot(...), store your plot as a variable and pass it to displayHTML().
# Make sure to specify output_type='div' as a keyword argument.
# (Note that if you call displayHTML() multiple times in the same cell, only the last will take effect.)

p = plot(
  [
    go.Histogram2dContour(x=x, y=y, contours=dict(coloring='heatmap')),
    go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker=dict(color='white', size=3, opacity=0.3))
  ],
  output_type='div'
)

displayHTML(p)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use `plotly` version 4.2, you no longer need to `import plotly.offline` and you can just call `fig.show()` on your figure created with Plotly Express or `go.Figure()`. The new renderer framework has a Databricks-specific renderer :)

Full documentation here: https://plot.ly/python/renderers/ and https://plot.ly/python/creating-and-updating-figures/

Comment: Hi, I'm getting "Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed" for plotly 4.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @nicolaskruchten answer,
Make sure your default renderer is set to:

```
pio.renderers.default = 'databricks'
```

-or-

Declare renderer as you show figure:

```
fig.show(renderer='databricks')
```